# Typescript call a method from a string dynamically

Tags: typescript, prismic.io

I'm used to use this type of dynamic method call in vanilla JS with @prismicio/client. But with typeScript, I get an issue :

```js
import Prismic from '@prismicio/client'

const options = {
    predicate: 'at',
    path: 'document.type',
    value: 'page'

}

Prismic.Predicates[options.predicate](options.path, options.value);
```

Unfortunately the parser tells me this :

```
{
    "resource": "/Users/a143ji/Projects/ai-marketplace-backend/src/prismic.ts",
    "owner": "typescript",
    "code": "7053",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'any' can't be used to index type '{ at(fragment: string, value: string | number | boolean | Date | (string | number | boolean | Date)[]): string; not(fragment: string, value: string | number | boolean | Date | (string | ... 2 more ... | Date)[]): string; ... 28 more ...; geopoint: { ...; }; }'.",
    "source": "ts",
    "startLineNumber": 11,
    "startColumn": 16,
    "endLineNumber": 11,
    "endColumn": 45
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `options` is mutable object and TS is unsure whether `options.predicate` could be used as index or not.

To fix it, you should add `as const` prefix to your object:

```js
import Prismic from '@prismicio/client'

const options = {
    predicate: 'at',
    path: 'document.type',
    value: 'page'

} as const

Prismic.Predicates[options.predicate](options.path, options.value); // ok
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBABSsAziYBjOAzKERwDkAAmMmpsBAPQYA2wApgHYyEBQ7GEzK8EYGFV5wAvHADe7ODLhlGAE0wBDGIwBcRVYQA002WFUALTYQUQMAVxAsYAOhgBPMI136ZAN2V1LGooYBzV04AXzhlFDhuXhhOaL44KEYUSzp4cSRUdAw7JEUVNRQAbQEhHhQ7eSUMVUYAXQAKUuEKwxgjHThm8rsvH0YASgBuOGpqOD5gKGYAoA)

Comment: It should work, see update, I added playground link 1 minute ago